# PHP how to explode string into groups of 6 letters in array

Tags: php

```
$string = 'billiejeanisnotmylover';
$array = some_function($string,6);

$array[0] = 'billie'
$array[1] = 'jeanis'
$array[2] = 'notmyl'
$array[3] = 'over'
```

do you have an idea what some_function would be?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [`str_split`](http://php.net/str_split):

```
$array = str_split($string, 6);
```